# Sonatype Nexus LDAP plugin installed but not able to activate

Tags: ldap, nexus

I just installed Nexus OSS 3.0.2-02. 
However, in the Realms menu there is no LDAP that I could add:

[image: realms missing ldap option]

Under Bundles, com.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-ldap-plugin is listed in version 3.0.2.02 as installed, but I don't see, how to activate it:

[image: ldap plugin listed under Bundles]

I tried grepping the nexuslog when I start Nexus, yet the plugin is not listed in the log at all. Not even like "failed to load..." or something.

Has somebody an idea or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have the same issue on a fresh install on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facing the same problem, I have digged in karaf console.

I've found this issue

```
com.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-ldap-plugin (206)
--------------------------------------------------
Status: Installed
Unsatisfied Requirements:
[com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-ldap-plugin [206](R 206.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.persist)
[com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-ldap-plugin [206](R 206.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.persist.entity)
```

But can't find any information on those missing dependencies.

Finally I've tried with the 3.0.1-01 version and ... it works out of the box.

So I guess it is a bug of this version.

I've left some comments in the Hipchat chan of nexus but can't find the github repo for the 3.X version so can't fill an issue.

Comment: I can confirm that an older version (3.0.1 for me too) solves the problem.